# defaultTreeModel nodes removed still shown in table

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treemodel

I am trying to remove nodes from a `DefaultTreeModel`. If I try to remove a single node, it doesn't get removed from the GUI. If I remove 2 nodes, only 1 of them is getting removed, etc.

I am using `removeNodeFromParent(node);` to remove the nodes.

Could someone please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your tree isn't detecting the `nodesWereRemoved` event that should be triggered by the `removeNodeFromParent(node);` method.

Are you using the standard `DefaultTreeModel` and `JTree` objects? If so, they should automatically refresh when doing a removal. If you've written a custom of either class, you're probably not handling the `nodesWereRemoved` event (in your custom `JTree`), or you're not triggering the event (in your custom `DefaultTreeModel`).

If you're using the standard objects, try calling `JTree.revalidate();` and `JTree.repaint();` after you remove the node, to force the tree to be repainted from your model change.

A final suggestion, have you tried any of the `removeXXX()` methods of `JTree` instead?